# Update some object properties

Tags: javascript

I have something like this :

```
let test = [
             {
              name: "Mark",
              address: "Some adress",
              company: "company name",
              age: 21
             }
]

let test1 = [
             {
              name: "Steve",
              age: 27
             }
    ]
```

How can I update test with test1? Thus, what I want to get is :

```
let test2 = [
             {
              name: "Steve",
              address: "Some adress",
              company: "company name",
              age: 27
             }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for it.

> The **`Object.assign()`** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
let test = [{ name: "Mark", address: "Some adress", company: "company name", age: 21 }],
    test1 = [{ name: "Steve", age: 27 }];

Object.assign(test[0], test1[0]);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: sorry, not necessary, because op ask a question with ES6 syntax (`let`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
test[0].name = test1[0].name;
test[0].age = test1[0].age;
```

Actually, you don't need to put the object as an array. Like this:

```
let test = {
      name: "Mark",
      address: "Some adress",
      company: "company name",
      age: 21
}
```

This way, you don't need to call it like this: `test[0].name` --> just do `test.name`